# Possible lengths of Monero addresses?

Tags: blockchain, address

I'm doing crude client-side verification of a form that includes an input for a Monero wallet. What are the possible lengths of an address? Are 106 and 95 the only possible lengths?

Answer (score 4):

For now, the are two used formats: standard (95 characters long) and integrated (106 characters long).

Subaddresses are a new type, but differ from standard addresses only by their prefix, so are also 95 characters long.